# Why php exec dont run gs command in my Mac OS X MAMP server?

Tags: php, macos, exec, mamp, ghostscript

I have a website that uses Ghostscritp to renderize some PDF files. After some troubles with Imagick, I decided to use the php exec command to run Ghostscipt gs command line manually. This is working just fine.

But in my localhost MAMP testing server it does not work. I did this php script to test and try to find why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $root = getcwd();
    $dirTemp = $root.'/teste';
    $imgTeste = new Imagick();
    echo('<h1>Teste</h1>');
    echo('<h2>Unix</h2>');
    echo('<h3>exec date</h3>');
    $Exec = array();
    $execResult = NULL;
    exec("date", $Exec, $execResult);
    echo('<div style="width:100%; height:200px; overflow:scroll; border:1px solid #000;"><p>Resultado: '.$execResult.'</p>');
    foreach($Exec as $linha){ echo('<p>'.$linha.'</p>'); }
    echo('</div>');
    echo('<h3>exec ls</h3>');
    $Exec = array();
    $execResult = NULL;
    exec("ls", $Exec, $execResult);
    echo('<div style="width:100%; height:200px; overflow:scroll; border:1px solid #000;"><p>Resultado: '.$execResult.'</p>');
    foreach($Exec as $linha){ echo('<p>'.$linha.'</p>'); }
    echo('</div>');
    echo('<h2>Ghostscript</h2>');
    echo('<h3>Info</h3>');
    $Exec = array();
    $execResult = NULL;
    exec("gs -h", $Exec, $execResult);
    echo('<div style="width:100%; height:200px; overflow:scroll; border:1px solid #000;"><p>Resultado: '.$execResult.'</p>');
    foreach($Exec as $linha){ echo('<p>'.$linha.'</p>'); }
    echo('</div>');
    echo('<h3>Teste</h3>');
    $arqTeste = $dirTemp."/teste.gs.jpeg";
    $arqTesteOrig = $root."/teste.pdf";
    if(is_file($arqTeste)){
        unlink($arqTeste);
        if(is_file($arqTeste)) die('<p>Não foi possível excluir o teste anterior!</p>');
    }
    echo('<p>Renderizar "'.$arqTesteOrig.'" para "'.$arqTeste.'"...');
    $gscmd = "gs -dSAFER -sDEVICE=jpeg -r75 -dDOINTERPOLATE -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -o ".$arqTeste." ".$arqTesteOrig;
    echo('<p>Ghostscript: '.$gscmd.'</p>');
    $Exec = array();
    $execResult = NULL;
    exec($gscmd, $Exec, $execResult);   
    echo('<div style="width:100%; height:200px; overflow:scroll; border:1px solid #000;"><p>Resultado: '.$execResult.'</p>');
    foreach($Exec as $linha){ echo('<p>'.$linha.'</p>'); }
    echo('</div>');
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($arqTeste);
    echo('<img src="temp/_teste.jpeg" '.$attr.' />');
    echo('<h2>Imagick</h2>');
    echo('<h3>Info</h3>');
    $Ver = $imgTeste->getVersion();
    foreach($Ver as $prop=>$val){ echo('<p>'.$prop.': '.$val.'</p>'); }
    echo('<p>Fim do Teste ---+</p>');
?>

</body>
</html>
```

This script do several tests. The two first exec commands works fine, but the gs command fails (the return is 127, I gess -1 or FALSE). The strange part is if I copy and paste the command line from browser (after "Ghostscript:") to Terminal (command line shell) it works! Why?

Comment: Probably the Ghostscript directory is not in the PATH of the PHP 'user'.You could try using a fully qualified path specification to the ghostscript executable instead of just 'gs'. If that works in your exec, then I would bet that's where the problem is.

Comment: Yes! Now it's working. In my case, the gs is in /usr/local/bin folder, I found it in Ghostscript reference. Now I'll have to find how to put this folder in PHP 'user'. You know how? Will be a good complete answer for the community.

Comment: I'm afraid I am neither a Linux expert nor in any sense knowledgeable about PHP. This: http://serverfault.com/questions/588218/change-apache-php-path-environment-variable-on-centos-with-cpanel might be helpful